# getting entire json data from API with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web

With my AJAX call, I want to get the json data entirely.

For example www.abc.com/api/3 gives  {"information":.... json data with many levels...}}

I want to store this data in variable.So I try this:

```
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {

                               x=data;// It's wrong, but I don't know how to put whole json into x

            }
        })
```

Comment: Initialize `x` with `let` or `var` to avoid cluttering up the global namespace. Otherwise, your code should work. What do you get logging `x` to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.ajax()` as a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises):

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```